# No upload button using FilePond ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload

Good day,

I am wanting to Use FilePond with Reactjs to facilitate  image uploads to a server.What I want is to have the file populate in the Pond like the description shows then for the **upload button** to appear for the user to upload the file.

Initially from using their demo code I noticed that it would auto-upload files and from reading the documentation I see that I disable that auto upload feature using "instantUpload={false}" in my server. However I have done this and I still don't have an upload button for the user to use. I read the documentation some more and they say I need to specify the server which I have . Is there something that I am missing to show the upload button in my code.

**Code below:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
/*import agent from "superagent";*/
import classNames from "classnames";
import cookie from 'react-cookies';

// Import React FilePond
import { FilePond, registerPlugin } from "react-filepond";

// Import FilePond styles
import "filepond/dist/filepond.min.css";

// Import the Image EXIF Orientation and Image Preview plugins
// Note: These need to be installed separately
import FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation from "filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation";
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from "filepond-plugin-image-preview";
import "filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css";

// Register the plugins
registerPlugin(FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation, FilePondPluginImagePreview);


export default class FotoUpload extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {
     // Set initial files, type 'local' means this is a file
     // that has already been uploaded to the server (see docs)
     files: [
       {
         source: "index.html",
         options: {
           type: "local"
         }
       }
     ]
   };
 }

 handleInit() {
   console.log("FilePond instance has initialised", this.pond);
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <div className="App">
       {/* Pass FilePond properties as attributes */}
       <FilePond
       ref={ref => (this.pond = ref)}
                  allowFilePoster={true}
                  instantUpload={false}
                  server=
                      {
                        {
                          url: 'http://mybackend.com:5000/upload/images',
                          process: {
                          headers: {
                                'cookie-token':  cookie.load('cookie')
                                  },
                            }
                          }
                        }
                  name="image"
                  acceptedFileTypes={['image/*']}
                  oninit={() => this.handleInit()}
         onupdatefiles={fileItems => {
           // Set currently active file objects to this.state
           this.setState({
             files: fileItems.map(fileItem => fileItem.file)
           });
         }}
       />
     </div>
   );
 }
}
```

If I  allow the instaupload feature the file will upload and success will return , but I will still not receive an Upload button.

**Myimage**

> As you can see there isn't an upload button like shown in the offical documentation.
>   [image: My image]

**Similar problem**
https://github.com/pqina/vue-filepond/issues/5

**FilePond Documentation** 
https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/server/

**Official repo**
https://github.com/pqina/react-filepond

Comment: What happens if you set `server` to `'http://mybackend.com:5000/upload/images'`

Comment: As it turns out this code works fine. The issue is that filepond has a lot going on in the background and I had code that was modifying and had to dig deep. I realised it when this code worked in a sandbox . So I removed a component and everything worked.